# How to open browsers in private/incognito mode with selenium?

Tags: ruby, cookies, selenium, incognito-mode

I'm writing Selenium tests in Ruby to test my website in multiple browsers.

However, the tests won't fire correctly unless the cookies are clear(there are triggers I'm testing that only happen X number of times and is stored in a cookie).

Does anyone know how to have selenium open a browser in its private browsing or incognito mode with Selenium or have another idea on how I might solve the issue?

Comment: clear the cookies at the end of each test?

Comment: Is there a way to automate that?

Comment: What is the test framework you are using?

Comment: selenium webdriver. No other framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Chrome to start in incognito by default.

There's a solution for Windows at the bottom of the link below... If you're not using Windows, you can Google how to achieve this for you OS =)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sYaZkNW8II4

Comment: I was having the most trouble with safari, any idea how to get that working properly? I'm using osx mavericks. The old safari cookie plugin doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: No idea how to get safari to start in incognito.. I almost never use Safari.